# Conditional dependent job in Azure Devops YAML pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm building a complex pipeline in yaml and I'm trying to create a dependency between two jobs such that the latter job runs after the former, but only if the former is set to run based on a parameter. I can't seem to wrap my head around whether this is doable or not.

I have a pipeline defined like this:

```
parameters:
- name: doJobA
  type: boolean

stages:
  jobs:
  - job: JobA
    condition: eq('${{ parameters.doJobA }}', true)
    # ... details removed for brevity

  - job: JobB
    dependsOn: JobA
    # ... details removed for brevity
```

`JobB` should run after `JobA` if `parameters.doJobA` is true, or immediately if `parameters.doJobA` is false. Simply adding the `dependsOn` condition causes `JobB` to be skipped if the `JobA` condition is not met which makes sense, but I'd like it to run regardless.

Is it possible to define a conditional `dependsOn` in this manner?

EDIT: I've run into an additional problem with this that renders the solution below unusable. I need the condition to depend upon a variable set by an earlier running PowerShell script and not based on parameters.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Simpler solution from https://elanderson.net/2020/05/azure-devops-pipelines-depends-on-with-conditionals-in-yaml/

```
parameters:
- name: doJobA
  type: boolean

stages:
  jobs:
  - job: JobA
    condition: eq('${{ parameters.doJobA }}', true)
    # ... details removed for brevity

  - job: JobB
    dependsOn: JobA
    condition: in(dependencies.JobA.result, 'Succeeded', 'Skipped')
    # ... details removed for brevity
```

Comment: This works for me - but I get a weird behavior after implementing it - when I try to cancel the stage, JobB keeps running until completion.  If I remove the condition, JobB will immediately cancel when the stage is cancelled.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code sample I came up with (you can see the [example](https://github.com/wesmacdonald/MCW-OSS-PaaS-and-DevOps/blob/master/azure-pipelines-conditions-demo.yml)).  Job 2 is always run, and is run after Job 1 if Job 1 runs.

### updated YAML

```
- job: One
  condition: eq('${{ parameters.DoJobOne }}', true)
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-2019'
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      throw "simulate Job One failing"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=JobOneRan;isOutput=true]true"
    name: setvarStep
  - script: |
      echo $(setvarStep.JobOneRan)          
    name: echovariable


- job: Two
  condition: and(always(), eq('${{ parameters.DoJobOne }}', eq(dependencies.One.outputs['setvarStep.JobOneRan'], true)))
  dependsOn: One
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-2019'
  variables:
    myVariableFromJobOne: $[ dependencies.One.outputs['setvarStep.JobOneRan'] ]
  steps:
  - script: echo $(myVariableFromJobOne)
    name: echovariable
```

Hope that helps.

Wes

Comment: I don' think' this solves the original question of having Job 2 run only based on a condition of Job 1 running

Comment: Wouldn't this always run job 2 even if job 1 fails?

Comment: Yes if Job 1 fails, Job 2 will run.  My understanding of the requirement was this: 

"JobB should run after JobA if parameters.doJobA is true, or immediately if parameters.doJobA is false. "

Comment: Thanks for the update Wes. Although the answer requires each job to set a variable through some script I think it's quite elegant.

Comment: When looking up this issue, I just saw there is a much simpler solution now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63992994/5165311

Answer (score 2):

I've found a slightly inelegant solution. By combining expressions with boolean parameters I'm able to do what I need, but it is a bit tricky:

```
parameters:
- name: doJobA
  type: boolean

stages:
  jobs:
  - job: JobA
    condition: eq('${{ parameters.doJobA }}', true)
    # ... details removed for brevity

  - job: JobB
    ${{ if eq(parameters.doJobA, true) }}:
      dependsOn: JobA
      condition: succeeded()
    # ... details removed for brevity
```

Here I insert a dependent clause only if the parameter `doJobA` is true. Otherwise it is not present. In order to ensure that `JobB` only runs if `JobA` succeeds I must also add a condition, but only if dependsOn is present.

The result is that the job runs immediately if `doJobA` is false because the resulting yaml will not contain any `dependsOn` or `condition` entries, but in the other case it will depend on the successful execution of `JobA`.

I'm still hoping there is a better way to achieve this though as this seems a bit complex (imo).

Edit: This solution only works for static properties and not dynamic variables.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here,  would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Comment: Unfortunately as I wrote in an edit on the initial question this does not solve my problem. This solution only works for static properties and not dynamically set variables which I need in order to get my template working. If you have any suggestions I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: This approach worked successfully for me with the only change I made being to define an expression for when doJobA is false

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works if your `JobA` parameter is a string. (Also works for boolean parameters)

```
parameters:
- name: doJobA
  type: string

stages:
  jobs:
  - job: JobA
    condition: eq('${{ parameters.doJobA }}', 'string')
    # ... details removed for brevity

  - job: JobB
    dependsOn: JobA
    condition: or(
                  and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters. doJobA }}', 'yourstring')), 
                  and(always(), ne('${{ parameters. doJobA }}', 'yourstring'))
                )

    # ... details removed for brevity
```